# Prove that $\dfrac{f(x)^2}{1+f(x)^2}\le C$.

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $ f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ be a continuous and non-zero function, $ a, b $ real numbers with $ a <b $. Prove that there exists a constant with $ 0 <C <1 $ such that $$\dfrac{f(x)^2}{1+f(x)^2}\le C$$

My attempt is the following, after touching that inequality a little, it is equivalent to demonstrating the following $$f(x)^2\leq \dfrac{C}{1-C}.$$

Since $ f $ is a continuous function and not zero, we can show that $ | f '(x) | <M $, where $ M <1 $ is a constant. In short, we can show that the derivative is bounded. Is there any way to say that if $ | f '(x) | <M $, then there is also a constant which satisfies that $ | f (x) | <P $ for a certain constant $ P <1 $?

Comment: How are $a,b$ related to your problem?

Comment: If $f=\exp$, there cannot be such a $0<C<1$ (for all $x\in\mathbb R$).

Comment: I really don't know. The statement of the question gives them. But I don't see any relevance to it. @nejimban

Comment: I am guessing $f$ should in fact be defined on a segment $[a,b]$ (and continuous there).

Comment: My guess is that you meant $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$. Then $$g : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}, \quad g(x)= \frac{f(x)^2}{1+f(x)^2}, \quad x \in [a,b].$$
is a continuous function defined on a segment $[a,b]$ and hence it attains a maximum at some $x_0 \in [a,b]$. For all $x \in [a,b]$ we have
$$\frac{f(x)^2}{1+f(x)^2} \le \frac{f(x_0)^2}{1+f(x_0)^2} < 1.$$
Moreover, since $f$ is nonzero it has to be $f(x_0) \ne 0$ so your desired number is $C := \frac{f(x_0)^2}{1+f(x_0)^2}$ and we have $0 < C < 1$.

Comment: Going forward, with your future mathSE questions, please make more of an effort to consider the question before posting, and proofread your posting.  You should have asked yourself what the relevance of $a,b$ were, and resolved this relevance (perhaps by communicating with your teacher) before you posted this question.  Responding by saying : "I don't really know", indicating that the issue is a *mystery* *to* *you* isn't really appropriate.  It is not unreasonable to ask that you *at* *least* *try* to resolve potential ambiguities before posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have omitted a constriction $a\leq x\leq b$. Else it is very easy to contruct a counter example (e.g. $f(x) = x$).

So then: $f$ in continuous on $[a,b]$. So $f^2$ takes a maximal value $M$. Now consider:
$$ \frac{x}{1+x}$$
for $x>0$ is growing (as can easily be seen by differentiation).

Thus
$$ \frac{f(x)^2}{1+f(x)^2} \leq \frac{M}{1+M} < 1$$

EDIT:
Elaborating on the growing aspect of $x/(1+x)$: The derivative of this is
$$ \frac1{1+x} - \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{1+x}\left(1-\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$$
as $x/(1+x)<1$ this will always be positive.

Comment: Note that $f$ non-zero is not nescessary here.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ c>0$ such that
$$(\forall x\in[a,b]) \; f(x)^2\le c$$

as $ f $ is continuous, we can take
$$c=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)^2\}$$

then
$$(\forall x\in [a,b])$$
$$\;1-\frac{1}{1+f(x)^2}\le 1-\frac{1}{1+c}<1$$

Comment: That is not true. If $f(x)^2 \geq c$ then $1/(1+f(x)^2)\leq 1/(1+c)$. Then $1-1/(1+f(x)^2)\geq 1- 1/(1+c)$.

Comment: @Lazy Thank you for the remark. I edited it.